# Will my phone still be unlocked after I install CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sim-unlocking

I've recently unlocked my phone so that it can work with any SIM card, and I want to install CyanogenMod.

What I'm wondering is, since CyanogenMod is going to wipe most of the data on the phone, is the lock status going to be changed too? i.e. will I end up with a locked phone again?

Edit: My phone is HTC One M8, previous locked to EE. I got the unlock code from EE.

Comment: What phone is it, and how did you sim unlock it? Mention it in the OP

Comment: @GokulNC, I've added the phone model to the post and how I've unlocked it.

Comment: Do you have the unlock code with you or can you get it again? And do you remember how to unlock it? If yes, proceed to flash CM. Or else, try to find if unlock code is stored in phone (requires root I guess).

Comment: See if this helps: **[How to SIM-Unlock Your HTC One for Free](http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/sim-unlock-your-htc-one-for-free-0155174/)**

Comment: Actually I've already unlocked my phone and it works fine with any SIM. What I want to know is will it still be unlocked after I install CyanogenMod? I know that from CM I cannot SIM unlock (it has to be done from the stock ROM), so I need the unlock status to be preserved. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: [Will flashing CyanogenMod reset the status of SIM lock on Nexus S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/108885/981), [Will flashing re-lock my unlocked phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32312/981)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No!**

CyanogenMod will wipe the **DATA** partition, all the **CACHE** partition and the **SYSTEM** partition while installing. It will not affect anything about lock/unlock of sim card.

Comment: I confirm. After installing CyanogenMod, the phone was still unlocked.